# How can I improve the focus on a skip to main content button in square space?

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I have a skip to main content button on a square space site I have been asked to look into and I can't figure out how to set the focus, the solutions for a regular html site do not work.

this is the current anchor tag I have toggeled as the "main content" to recieve focus after button click.

```
<a href="/contact" id="page" aria-label=" Get in touch, This link redirects to the contact us page" tabindex="0" class="first"> Get In Touch </a>
```

and this is the skip to main content anchor tag that I do not have direct access to because I assume square space automatically populates the header as I was unable to find any way to access the header.

```
<a href="#page" tabindex="1" class="header-skip-link sqs-button-element--primary" id="skiptomaincontent" aria-label="Skip to Main content">
      Skip to Content
    </a>
```

As this is square space I do not have direct access to the header where the button and navigation links are at.

Here are the solutions I tried that were successful in adding an id and aria label to the button

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('header-skip-link sqs-button-element--primary')[0].setAttribute("id", "skiptomaincontent");
 document.getElementById("skiptomaincontent").setAttribute("aria-label", "Skip to Main content")
});
```

and here is the code I tried to get the focus to go to the tag with the main content of page

```
   document.getElementsByClassName('header-skip-link sqs-button-element--primary')[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("page").focus();
```

One thing I have noticed is that even with out the focus code on the section above for some reason I have to hit tab a 2nd time after initally hitting enter in order to skip the links and get to the anchor tag so it IS skipping the links but it is not working the way it normally would, also on mobile the skip  doesn't work so I am hoping someone here can give me some guidance.